# What's the meaning of "receive top billing"

Tags: phrase-meaning

In the game "Batman:Arkham Knight", a riddle is

> Business is best when Bats need killing, a mercenary's file should receive **top billing**.

Does the phrase "top billing" means the best one?
And what's the meaning of whole sentence?

Comment: "Top Billing" is a phrase from theatre and cinema. 'Billing' is where you appear on 'bills', the old word for posters and other printed promotions; and the biggest star's name is the first listed, in big letters. Look at [this](http://theatrelitwiki.wikispaces.com/file/view/hamlet-1756-playbill-361x541%20(1).jpg/429363900/280x430/hamlet-1756-playbill-361x541%20(1).jpg) 18th century playbill, and notice where Mr. Garrick's name appears.

Comment: ...which is to say, yes: the top billing is the best one – the most prestigious  one – on a playbill.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by others, "top billing" refers to being first on a playbill, or more generally a top advertising priority. In this case, though, "top billing" might also mean top pay. The meaning of the sentence might be that when someone needs to kill Batman (Bats) a mercenary would be the best choice.

Comment: If "top billing" means top pay,then what's the meaning of the word "file"?Bank account?And this sentence is a pun,right?